# Why `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0` with `main` method arguments

Tags: java, arrays, timestamp

Where is the mistake in my code?

```
package My;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat; 
import java.util.Date; 
public class Hello { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Date now = new Date(); 
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = 
        new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(now); 
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "> Hello, " + args[0] + "!"); 
    }
}
```

out put is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at My.Hello.main(Hello.java:11)

}
```

Comment: Have you provided run time arguments to your program?

Comment: Didn't use a command line parameter?

Comment: Read the javadoc for `arrayindexoutofboundsexception` to see what it means. After this, it will be pretty easy to spot the failure.

Comment: Also you might want to consider indenting your code...

Comment: yes i provided arguments

Comment: You obviously haven't. Check your configuration.

Comment: Can you show *how* you provided arguments?

Comment: Do not confuse JVM arguments with program arguments. And no, you did not provide any "program argument"

Comment: You *already posted this* and it was closed: Dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118605/need-help-to-learn-java?rq=1

Comment: i provided the arguments in run configuration

Comment: @BrianRoach To be fair this question is better then previous one because it contains informations about problem (exception) so in this form it is "answerable". IMHO first question should be deleted instead of closing this one as duplicate.

Comment: Then you aren't using the _correct_ run configuration.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP needs to have a minimal understanding of the question topic.  This is material which could be solved by an introduction tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass arguments from the command line.Refer the **[official docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)**.

### Code:

```
package My;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date now = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter =
        new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(now);
        System.out.println(formattedDate + "> Hello, " + args[0] + "!");
    }
}
```

### Compilation and Execution:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

JVM throw exception bcoz no element exist at index 0 in the array.So provide the parameter during running the class or just add below code so that no exception will raise :

```
    if(args.length >= 1)
       {
           System.out.println(formattedDate + "> Hello, " + args[0] + "!"); 
       }
```

Pass the argument as below :

```
java My.Hello BHARAT
```